# Emulator for running PlayStation 2 games or images

Tags: gratis, windows-7, emulator

I tested a few emulators for running PlayStation 2 games on PC, but all of those I tried (PCSX2, and some more which I can’t remember) either:

- Had bad performance (running slow)
- or did not run some of the games

Requirements:

- Same performance as the hardware
- Can run any game the hardware can run
- Can open images like `.iso`
- [Freeware]

Please answer with software that you have already tested before ;).

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- CPU: Intel Core 2 Due

Comment: *"Please answer with software that you have already tested it before"* How about **you first mention the software that you already tested** and why they specifally did not meet the requirements (e.g. what games did not run under which emulator). Without that info you waste peoples time doing recommendations you have already rejected.

Comment: @JanDoggen Well!, I forgot the names, But one of them was `PCSX2`, Pardon me ;).

Answer (score 2):

[PCSX2](http://pcsx2.net/) is the **only** viable options when it comes to PS2 emulation.

All the other existing ones are either abandoned, little more than proof-of-concepts / early alphas, or even worse fakes/viruses.

Emulation in general is a very heavy task, and it requires hardware much more paowerful than the original to run ad decent speeds. Your "Same performance as the hardware" requirement is out of the question when it comes to emulation.

I would suggest you to try and fiddle with the many options present in pcsx2. Try to lower the settings and enable speedhacks to obtain more playable speeds. In general, try to follow the [configuration guide](http://pcsx2.net/config-guide/official-english-pcsx2-configuration-guide.html) for the best results.
Also note that you can search for a specific game on the [pcsx2 wiki](http://wiki.pcsx2.net/index.php/Main_Page) to see which options and hack are recommended to use for each specific game, as well as general compatibility information and known bugs.

This having been said, there's no escaping from the fact that you need a [powerful CPU to make it run](http://emulation.gametechwiki.com/index.php/Computer_specs#PCSX2), regardless of the settings. And some games aren't supported, for the simple fact that the original hardware is largely undocumented and developers have to reverse-engineer it "blindly".

For more info on PS2 emulation: [EmuGeneral wiki](http://emulation.gametechwiki.com/index.php/PlayStation_2)